# Installing ettercap-gtk on mac osx lion.

Tags: installation, osx-lion, macports, gtk

I'm trying to get ettercap-gtk installed on osx but am having little luck.  Getting ettercap without the GUI installed was no problem.  When I try with macports I get the following:

```
Package ettercap-gtk has no available version, but exists in the database.
This typically means that the package was mentioned in a dependency and
never uploaded, has been obsoleted or is not available with the contents
of sources.list
However the following packages replace it:
ettercap 
E: Package ettercap-gtk has no installation candidate
```

Any and all help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ettercap can be installed now on Mac via brew.

Make sure you have brew installed: https://brew.sh/

Install Ettercap: `brew install ettercap --with-gtk+`